# How to debug GitHub Actions workflow faster?

Tags: github-actions

I find it unproductive to edit yml file, then push a new commit again, and repeat the process hundreds of times until you make it right. I began thinking about how to automate this tedious process.

I tried GitHub Actions logging but doesn't help much.

Answer (score 7):

Install [actionlint](https://github.com/rhysd/actionlint) and [nektos/act](https://github.com/nektos/act) on your local machine.

- Lint your workflow with `actionlint`. Fix issues if any.
- After linting, run your workflow with `act`. Update your workflow if required and proceed accordingly.

If you're using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) then you can install [Github Actions Locally](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alphaxek.github-actions-locally) extension. It's in its beta so proceed accordingly. It uses `nektos/act` under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit/Update:

GitHub just [announced a VS Code extension](https://github.blog/2023-03-28-announcing-the-github-actions-extension-for-vs-code/) which you can use.

> Today, we’re excited to announce the release of the public beta of the official [GitHub Actions VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=github.vscode-github-actions). The extension provides support for authoring and editing workflows and helps you manage workflow runs without leaving your IDE.

---

In addition to [Azeem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75705690/5078746), you can install [`YAML` extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml) for VSCode.

For Jetbrains' tools refer to [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-223504/Support-completion-for-GitHub-Actions#focus=Comments-27-4329437.0-0):

On the bottom right, click on "No JSON Schema"

[image]

Then choose "GitHub workflow"

[image]

Basically, you want that your IDE or text editor to load [Github Actions' JSON schema](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/master/src/schemas/json/github-workflow.json).

Answer (score 0):

[mxschmitt/action-tmate](https://github.com/mxschmitt/action-tmate) lets you SSH into the runner by adding a step like

```yaml
    - name: Setup tmate session
      uses: mxschmitt/action-tmate@v3
```

There is a [roadmap item](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/637) to add similar functionality natively in Q3 of 2023.